# Is it defined behavior to change an Objective-C object's isa?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic-typing

In Objective-C, you can change an object's dynamic type at runtime by assigning to it's `isa` member variable:

```
id object = ...;
object->isa = [SomeClass class];
```

Is this undefined behavior?  I'm currently doing this as a kludge for something else, and it appears to be working, but I feel so dirty doing it this way.  The new class I'm setting doesn't add any member variables, it just overrides one method and adds a new one, so the class size is the same.  I feel like if I changed the object size, much badness would result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C: How to change the class of an object at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512793/objective-c-how-to-change-the-class-of-an-object-at-runtime)

Comment: You can run into to problems with KVO. They use isa-swizzling too. Mike Ash has a complete solution however: http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-11-19-creating-classes-at-runtime-for-fun-and-profit.html

Answer (score 1):

I think this is, as you say, dirty.

I suspect it will work if:

- The newly assigned class is a subclass of the real class.
- The new class doesn't add any member variables.

But I'll admit I don't know the nuts-and-bolts implementation of your Objective-C runtime system.  I just know what makes sense to me for an implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The Objective-C runtime now provides a function to do this: `object_setClass`. The documentation doesn't say what restrictions there are, but (as others have stated) I imagine you would want to restrict the new class to a class with exactly the instance variable layout as the original class.

Answer (score 0):

It's really bad form to change these, and it makes all sorts of assumptions about runtime behaviour -- you're much better off using the [runtime functions](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html) although they don't provide you with a mechanism to directly change the class.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8512834/330914) by Joshua Weinberg provides the right way to do this. It worked for me. :)

And Darron was right with his educated guess :) it will only work if it's a superclass of the current object, and if you don't add any members.