# How to set a UINavigationController's UINavigationBar class programmatically?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, background-image

I want to add a [Custom UINavigationBar Background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6959354/242933).

Is there anyway I can do this completely in code? `_navigationBarClass` seems to be a private property on `UINavigationController`.

[Objective-C: How to change the class of an object at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512793/objective-c-how-to-change-the-class-of-an-object-at-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

While not programmatic it can be done via Storyboards by setting the Navigation Bar class.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42989418/47281.