# How to change the custom class of a view by code

Tags: uiview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

How can I set the class for the same view when I preform a swipe on the view?
I have already imported the header files for the classes that I want to change to for example `#import "Circuit1.h"`

```
- (IBAction)userSwiped:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    [self numberOfSwips];

    self.numberOfSwips+=1;
    if (self.numberOfSwips>3){
        self.numberOfSwips=3;
    }
    if (self.numberOfSwips ==1) {
        self.myView.class =super.Circuit1;}
    else if (self.numberOfSwips ==2){
        self.myView.class =super.Circuit2;}
    else if (self.numberOfSwips ==3){
     self.myView.class =super.Circuit3;
    }
    NSLog(@"%f",self.numberOfSwips);
}
```

It's giving me an error for `self.myView.class = super.Circuit1` and the other 2

Comment: property "Circuit1" is not found on object in "viewController

Comment: 1. Have you declared `circuit1` in the header?
2. Have you checked to see if the view controller exists in the `Compile Sources`?
3. Have you tried cleaning the project? (command+alt+shift+K)

Comment: I did do 1 : #import "Circuit1.h"
didnt get the second point , can u explain it more please

Comment: I asked if you've `declare`d it, not `import`ed it. Try 1, 2 and 3 and see if they help.

Comment: how do u declare it ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+declare+an+ibar+in+objective+c&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIR503IR503&oq=how+to+declare+an+ibar+in+objective+c&aqs=chrome..69i57.6832j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Comment: I dont think U can declare a class

Comment: Of course you cannot declare a `class`. Your error message says that `circuit1` is a `property` not a `class`:
"property "Circuit1" is not found on object in "viewController"

You need to read some documentations and tutorials. Study more.

Comment: I understand what the error says . Im not sure wither or not self.myView.class =super.Circuit1 is the correct way to change the class of the view . if u know how to change the class of a UIView by using how please mention it , I looked in several books and web ites and I didnt find it

Answer (score 0):

Changing the class of an Objective-C object at runtime is technically possible, but is a **bad** idea. See [Objective-C: How to change the class of an object at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8512793/objective-c-how-to-change-the-class-of-an-object-at-runtime) for a good explanation of why.

However, it is possible to declare a variable of type `Class`, and use the value stored in it to instantiate an object:

```
Class customClass = [Circuit1 class];
```

and then something like this:

```
[myView removeFromSuperview]; 
myView = [customClass alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
[containerView addSubView:myView];
```

but this would involve recreating the view each time the user swiped. I don't know what exactly your code does, but if the views are complex this is almost certainly the wrong way to go. If you only have 3 subviews, perhaps it would be better to create them as needed, store them in an instance variable array in the viewController, and swap them in and out of the view hierarchy when the user swipes

Comment: thanks u , the reason why I want to be able to change the class of  a view controller is to change the display where in there are different drawing in each class